# how to type numpy function taking generic array

Tags: python, numpy, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

According to the [numpy documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/typing.html#numpy.typing.NBitBase), to declare a generic numpy type I should use `np.floating[T]` with `T = TypeVar("T", bound=npt.NBitBase)`. Then NDarray takes a scalar type. How do I combine the two to create a function that takes a generic array of floating? The following:

```py
T = TypeVar("T", bound=npt.NBitBase)


def entropy(x: npt.NDArray[np.floating[T]]) -> np.floating[T]:
    return cast(np.floating[T], np.sum(x * np.log(x)))
```

Gives me: `TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: What's a `generic array of floating`?

Comment: either 32 or 64 bit (or other as supported...)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the docs you linked, seems to me that this can be achieved with `dtype` numpy class ([docs here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html)) which accepts numpy generic types and can be provided to a `np.ndarray` as the array's data type.

This is how your code would look like considering what mentioned above:

```
# T is no longer needed
import numpy as np

def entropy(x: np.ndarray[int, np.dtype[np.float64]]) -> np.dtype[np.float64]:
    return cast(np.dtype[np.float64], np.sum(x * np.log(x)))
```

Either 32 or 64 bit can be specified in the numpy generic type: `np.float[64 | 32]`

Comment: You are on to something; but that is not what I'm looking for. It needs to be declared as generic. `np.ndarray[int, np.dtype[np.floating[T]]]` does work though. When I have a moment will run through mypy and see if it works. Maybe just np.floating without `T` is sufficient.